# Do HDMI splitters always work? Or is it a GPU compatibility?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, gpu

I want to buy the geforce gtx 750 ti GPU. I have an hdtv and I'm buying an hd monitor.
But the gpu only has one hdmi port. I would just put my tv on dvi but it doesn't have a dvi port. Only hdmi and vga. Can I buy a splitter so I can hook up my tv and the monitor to the gpu for extended desktop?

Comment: If your buying a "monitor" (not tv) you could just buy a DVI connecting monitor, then the TV is used on the HDMI as intended, and the DVI would be used on the computer monitor as intended.  What am I missing?

Comment: The only reason why you would prefer an HDMI for your monitor, is if you would have built-in speakers in the monitor. HDMI monitors don't perform any better than their DVI equivalents, they only cost more because HDMI costs money to implement (patent rights).

Comment: I checked they have 750 ti with dual hdmi http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007709%20600106604&IsNodeId=1&name=2%20x%20HDMI (as example only not recomendation).   Wonder if they would handle all the audio correctally.

Comment: I figured hdmi was sharper than dvi so I wanted to hook up the hdmi to my monitor since I'd use that as my primary screen

Comment: Both DVI and HDMI use basically the same digital Video signals when hooking up to these GPUs, if one or the other is being interpolated improperly there are (usually) adjustements for that. Then the resolution that is run at, other than (usually) solveable problems, sharpness shouldnt change, only because of the connection for the digital signal.  If anything gets odd things happening it is the HDMI TVs (not monitors) that have overscan and purposfull interpoaltion for tv going on, or lower resolutions, not the DVI only monitors.